# Regex minifier tool

Tags: regex

Software/tool that takes a regular expression and gives equivalent shorter versions. That is, the two regexes would match the same strings with the same captured strings and will not match the same strings.

E.g.:

```
([0123456789]|[0-67-9][0-789]|) -> ([0-9]{0,2})
this[REG]exwontmatchanythin[]gbecauseoftheemptycharacterclass -> []

((?:g(?:im?|mi?)?|i(?:gm?|mg?)?|m(?:gi?|ig?)?)?) ->
  (g?i?m?|gmi|ig?m?|img|mg?i?|mig)
```

I don't need it to be a certain flavour, but would prefer it if it was either Perl, PHP, Python or Javascript.

Comment: Your first example has a better/shorter answer of  `(\d{0,2})`.

Comment: @SteveBarnes No, because `\d` usually includes multilanguage/Unicode digits, like ௫ or ３, which `[0-9]` donsn't

Comment: The only one I'm aware of is https://github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/regexp-tree. It currently only handles JS regexps.

Also, note that you first answer is actually not equivalent, because of the order in the disjunction.

Comment: This is not a simple problem. The algorithmic way to simplify a regular expression is to convert it into an [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), then into a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), then [minimize it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization), then convert that DFA back into a regular expression. This may also require knowing the alphabet (set of allowed characters).

Comment: @GolmoteKinoko Looking at that optimizer, it only supports simple optimizations. https://github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/regexp-tree/tree/master/src/optimizer#transforms